# Linking together multiple tables to grab information from each

Tags: sql, database, join

I am creating a page that displays info on equipment that has been scanned into and out of my office. The way I want it to display is

Equipment Name        User(Headtech)     Event used    Returned(Y/N)

The problem is the SQL tables are everywhere and joining them all is proving to be difficult. There needs to be a chain going through three tables to get the Head tech name, this was not of my design and I can not change it.

What I currently have

```
     $select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *
                                  FROM equipment 
                                  JOIN pay 
                                    ON pay.eventid = equipment.eventid
                                  JOIN personnel 
                                    ON personnel.workerid = (pay.eventid WHERE role = 'aht')
                                  JOIN events
                                    ON events.id = equipment.eventid
                                  WHERE status='3' 
                                  ORDER By timeOut DESC");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $timeIn = $row['timeIn'];
        $timeOut = $row['timeOut'];
        $eventID = $row['eventid'];                     
      echo "<div><div class='rowBoxS'>$name</div>";
        $htName = $row['personnel.first'] . " " . $row['perosnnel.last'];
        echo "<div class='rowBoxS'>$htName</div>";  
            $event = $row['eventName'];                
            echo "<div class='rowBoxS'>$event</div>";

            if ($timeOut > 0){
              echo "<div class='rowBoxS'>$</div></div>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<div class='rowBoxS'>Failed to return</div></div>";
            }
```

This is clearly not working as intended, and I'm very aware that that is probably not how joining works especially with the pay.eventid WHERE role = 'aht' bit. I want to know if there is a proper way to approach this. I tried looking it up, but most people probably have clean databases they are working with and couldn't possibly run into this problem.

Edit:
All the tables are on the same server. The problem is if I want to get someone's name you need to use the eventid row from equipment on the pay table find that id, then through the 'role' row find the user with AHT role and then take that persons workerid into the personnel table where you can finally find the persons name.

Comment: By term _Databases_ do you mean **Tables**?

Comment: Yes I do mean Tables. I wrote the wrong word the first time and then used it all the way through. It's fixed now thanks for pointing it out.